# JavaScript: Converting RSS into JSON in AWS Lambda Node app

Tags: javascript, json, aws-lambda, rss, rss-reader

I'm currently working on writing a function on AWS Lambda. I want to convert a RSS feed into a JSON and give that as a response in the body when making to the Lambda endpoint.

I'm using an [npm package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/rss-to-json) to convert the RSS to JSON. However, when I run the code. I see that I get undefined in the conversion of the RSS URL. Here is the following code:

```
const feed = require('rss-to-json');

exports.handler = async (event) => {
  let rssFeed = event.queryStringParameters.rssFeed;
  let rssAsJsonData = convertRssIntoJson(rssFeed);

  return sendRes(200, rssAsJsonData);
};

const sendRes = (status, body) => {
  var response = {
    isBase64Encoded: true|false,
    statusCode: status,
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json"
    },
    body: body,
  };
  return response;
};

function convertRssIntoJson (rssFeed) {
  console.log(rssFeed);
  return feed.load(rssFeed, function(err, rss){
    if(err) {
      console.log("Error: ${err}");
      return;
    }
    console.log(rss)
    return rss;
  });
};
```

However, in the logs I get `undefined` when `console.log(rssAsJsonData)`. 
[image]

However, when debugging I was able to see `console.log(rss)` working when I change body to be `body: json.stringify("TESTING")`
[image]

However, it only worked when logging to the console not when I tried to pass it to the body `body: body,` I can't seem to find what the error is. I'm moving from Ruby to JavaScript for this project maybe I'm missing something.

I'm using Postman to make the calls: 
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function convertRssIntoJson (rssFeed) {
  console.log(rssFeed);
  return feed.load(rssFeed, function(err, rss){
    if(err) {
      console.log("Error: ${err}");
      return;
    }
    console.log(rss)
    return rss;
  });
};
```

The piece of code above is a callback. Under the hood, feed.load is asynchronous, which makes your callback be executed asynchronously.

Now, when you invoke your function like this

```
let rssAsJsonData = convertRssIntoJson(rssFeed);
```

your `rss` object inside `convertRssIntoJson` does not hold any value yet, because the callback hasn't been populated up to now. This is where your `undefined` comes from.

Callbacks themselves don't make code asynchronous by default, but NodeJS works with a non-blocking IO model and, since feed.load is an IO call, it will be executed asynchronously.

You have a few options now, but I will list only two. A not-so-nice and a nice solution:

1) The not-so-nice way to fix it is to add a callback as argument to your `convertRssIntoJson` function and pass the value of that `rss` object upstream. The not-so-nice full code can be found below:

```
const feed = require('rss-to-json');

exports.handler = async (event) => {
    let rssFeed = event.queryStringParameters.rssFeed;

    convertRssIntoJson(rssFeed, (err, data) => {
        if (err) {
            return sendRes(500, { message: 'There was an err: ' + err.message })
        }
        return sendRes(200, data)
    })
};

const sendRes = (status, body) => {
    var response = {
        isBase64Encoded: true | false,
        statusCode: status,
        headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json"
        },
        body: body,
    };
    return response;
};

const convertRssIntoJson = (rssFeed, callback) => {
    console.log(rssFeed);
    feed.load(rssFeed, function (err, rss) {
        if (err) {
            console.log("Error: ${err}");
            callback(err, undefined)
        }
        console.log(rss)
        callback(undefined, rss)
    });
};
```

2) The nice, clean, elegant and recommended solution is this one. Wrap your callback in a Promise, like this

```
function convertRssIntoJson(rssFeed) {
    console.log(rssFeed);
    return new Promise((res, rej) => {
       feed.load(rssFeed, function (err, rss) {
            if (err) {
                console.log("Error: ${err}");
                return rej(err)
            }
            console.log(rss)
            return res(rss)
        });
    })
};
```

Since your handler is `async`, it means it can just `await` on Promises.

So your client code is now as simple as:

```
return sendRes(200, await convertRssIntoJson(rssFeed));
```

Your final code will look like (I have refactored a little bit to make use of arrow functions):

```
const feed = require('rss-to-json');

exports.handler = async (event) => {
    let rssFeed = event.queryStringParameters.rssFeed;

    return sendRes(200, await convertRssIntoJson(rssFeed));
};

const sendRes = (status, body) => {
    var response = {
        isBase64Encoded: true | false,
        statusCode: status,
        headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json"
        },
        body: body,
    };
    return response;
};

const convertRssIntoJson = (rssFeed) => {
    console.log(rssFeed);
    return new Promise((res, rej) => {
        feed.load(rssFeed, (err, rss) => {
            if (err) {
                console.log("Error: ${err}");
                return rej(err)
            }
            console.log(rss)
            return res(rss)
        });
    })
};
```

If you want to know more about async/await, you can see it in [here](https://javascript.info/async-await).

***EDIT***: Code refactor and code added for solution 1)